# Set value to true if id is present in a string linq

Tags: c#, linq

I have the following field in a table:

> AllowedUsers : Is of type varchar(50) with user ids separated with commas.

I have to set a boolean value according if the connected user id of my application in present in this "list" of allowed users.
Any idea of how to this?

My query is as below:

```
(from user in db.FindAll(usr => usr.Email.Equals(userLogin.Username) && 
usr.Password.Equals(userLogin.Password))
join office in db.FindAll() on user.OfficeId equals office.Id
select new UserDetails()
{
    UserID = user.Id,
    Language = user.Language,
    OfficeId = user.OfficeId,
    IsAllowed = user.Id.ToString().Contains(office.AllowedUsers)
}
);
```

However this is not working.
Any helpp please?

Comment: _"type varchar(50) with user ids separated with commas"_ why that mess? Those users belong into another table which is linked via foreign-key.

Comment: try swapping the expression : `office.AllowedUsers.Contains(user.Id.ToString())`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The collection contains the user-id, not the user-id contains the collection. But since `String.Split` isn't available in Linq-To-Sql or Linq-To-Entities you need to use `Linq-To-Objects` with `AsEnumerable`. Note that you should filter before because everything after `AsEnumerable` will be streamed into memory.

```
var loginUser = 
    from user in db.FindAll(usr => usr.Email.Equals(userLogin.Username) && usr.Password.Equals(userLogin.Password))
    join office in db.FindAll() on user.OfficeId equals office.Id
    select new { user, office };

var userDetails = from u in loginUser.AsEnumerable()
    select new UserDetails()
    {
        UserID = u.user.Id,
        Language = u.user.Language,
        OfficeId = u.user.OfficeId,
        IsAllowed = u.office.AllowedUsers.Split(',').Contains(u.user.Id.ToString())
    };
```

But you should really fix this mess because it's too late. 
Those users belong into another table which is linked via foreign-key.

Comment: I tried your solution but I am getting the error: A query body must end with a select clause or a group clause.

Answer (score 1):

Your Contains is the wrong way around:

```
var result = (from user in db.FindAll(usr => usr.Email.Equals(userLogin.Username) && 
usr.Password.Equals(userLogin.Password))
join office in db.FindAll() on user.OfficeId equals office.Id
select new 
{
    UserID = user.Id,
    Language = user.Language,
    OfficeId = user.OfficeId,
    IsAllowed = false,
    AllowedUsers = office.AllowedUsers
}
).ToList();

var final = result.Select(c=> new UserDetails {
    UserID = c.Id,
    Language = c.Language,
    OfficeId = c.OfficeId,
    IsAllowed = c.AllowedUsers.Split(",").Contains(user.Id.ToString())
});
```

Comment: `AllowedUsers` is a `varchar`, you need to use Split (which doesn't work if you don't use Linq.-To-Objects). Consider it is `9,10` and you check if it contains `1`. It will return true because `10` contains `1`.

Comment: @Tjaart: This works. Thanks.  But there is one small issue:

Since the user ids are separated by commas, if I have user with id 1 connected
and in the list of AllowedUsers i have like 19, 20, 23.  This will set the boolean to true despite 1 not being present in the AllowedUsers. How can I solve this?

Comment: @Rango: you got my point.  Do you have any workaround to this problem?

Comment: I changed my answer @tabby , try the above